# Does the ASUS M4A78T-E support UEFI?

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I am trying to connect a [Seagate ST3000DM001 3TB](http://www.seagate.com/internal-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/desktop-hdd/?sku=ST3000DM001) drive to my Ubuntu 14.04 build on an [ASUS M4A78T-E](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A78TE/). In the bios, it shows that nothing is detected from the SATA port the 3TB drive is connected to.

All I could find was a post from [this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/archive/index.php/t-7500-p-199.html) forum.

```
Manufacturer: Asus
Model: M4A78T-E (http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/M4A78TE/)
Bios Type: AMI
Bios Revision: 3503
Bios Download Link: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM3/M4A78T-E/M4A78T-E-ASUS-3503.zip

SLIC: Asus 2.1
SLP: Asus, HP

Modded with AMI SLIC Mod v1.63
Mod method: SSV3/MMTool (+ Insert SLP string in IBM region)
```

If the BIOS type is AMI, is it impossible to have this PC read a 3TBhard drive? Could I get an external enclosure and connect via USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear on whether the board itself—or the SATA controller—is the root of the issue. According to the official specs page, the controller uses a [SB750 south bridge chipset](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A78TE/specifications/) which I believe would control what types of drives can be connected & how they would be utilized. But when you ask this:

> Could I get an external enclosure and connect via USB?

My answer to *that specific question* is yes, you can use an external USB enclosure for your drive as long as the enclosure can handle 3TB and larger SATA drives. The core issue is most likely the SATA controller on your motherboard. A good way around that would be to use a USB external enclosure.

Comment: I tried installing the latest AMD Catalyst for linux and now get black screens when I boot. I guess I'll go with the USB external solution